# C# Expression Bodied Constructor - Is there a way to combine with null checking?

Tags: c#-7.0

**Is there a recommended or prefered way to combine C#7  "Expression Bodied Constructors" with other activities, such as null checking and exception throwing?**

When writing a C# class, I am accustomed to being able to test arguments for nulls (and throw exceptions if needed) in my constructor, like this:-

```
class Person
{
   private string _name;
   private SomeClass _someClass; 

   public Person(string name, SomeClass someClass)
   {
       _name = name ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(name));
       _someClass = someClass?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(someClass));
   }
}
```

I have just learned about **Expression Bodied Constructors**, where a simple version of my code could look like this:-

```
class Person
{
   private string _name;
   private SomeClass _someClass; 

   public Person(string name, SomeClass someClass)
      => (_name, _someClass) = (name, someClass);

}
```

The above initially seems appealing because of the potential to reduce the amount of boilerplate code needed to assign arguments to member variables.

However, I seem to have lost the opportunity to include activities such as the aforementioned null checking, as there is no longer a constructor body.

As far as I can tell, the only way around this is to inline code, such as my null-coalesce check, like this :-

```
...
   public Person(string name, SomeClass someClass)
      => (_name, _someClass) = 
        (
         name ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(name ), 
         someClass ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(someClass)
        ));
```

Even though I have attempted to improve legibility through spacing, in my opinion, the above is not as easy to read as the original example - and has not really saved any typing.

Q:  Is there a better way that I could approach this, or am I defeating the purpose of this new style of constructor?   (i.e. should I just stick with the original approach)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to criticize you for trying.

The fact is that both versions generate pretty much the same code.

```
class Person
{
   private string _name;
   private string _someClass; 

   public Person(string name, string someClass)
   {
       _name = name ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(name));
       _someClass = someClass?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(someClass));
   }
}
```

becomes

```
class Person
{
    private string _name;

    private string _someClass;

    public Person(string name, string someClass)
    {
        if (name == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("name");
        }
        _name = name;
        if (someClass == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("someClass");
        }
        _someClass = someClass;
    }
}
```

[see it on sharplab.io](https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgDABFAjAbgLACgoCY4AUCmATgM4D2AdhgN4Zx0AOhAlgG4CGALvgovAPrk2AW3xp0dOI1aduSfmREBhADZtixZHAy06UAMx4iZcgAo5cQSIA0PeAvwq1xAJQ64NcRIkDh3ALwWvnAA/MFwHAAWhKQA7hb4cQCChADmAK4i5BwAcmnKygCiAB4Axvj0HEwUJpb4pABmNb7OzmJe3vaO6nABnarqoeFRsfFJqRn4Wbn5xWUVVaa1DSZ9Ti1tdAC+GJtAA)

and

```
class Person
{
   private string _name;
   private string _someClass; 

   public Person(string name, string someClass)
       => (_name, _someClass) = 
           (
               name ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(name)), 
               someClass ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(someClass))
           );
}
```

becomes

```
class Person
{
    private string _name;

    private string _someClass;

    public Person(string name, string someClass)
    {
        if (name == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("name");
        }
        if (someClass == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("someClass");
        }
        _name = name;
        _someClass = someClass;
    }
}
```

[see it on sharplab.io](https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgDABFAjAbgLACgoCY4AUCmATgM4D2AdhgN4Zx0AOhAlgG4CGALvgovAPrk2AW3xp0dOI1aduSfmREBhADZtixZHAy06UAMx4iZcgAo5cQSIA0PeAvwq1xAJQ6JdALwA+OCYHD8Gz57R3VnOA8tcXcY3zdY2MtuAH5kuA4AC0JSAHcLfDyAQUIAcwBXEXIOADky5WUAUQAPAGN8eg4mChMk0gAzHoDnZxt4hPcQ1XU4VPSs3Pyi0or8Ktr65raOrtNegcmnYbHY5zEAXyA==)

Answer (score 0):

I see the "Tuple assignment" style as a nice brief way to say "my class is initialised from these members and nothing else is going on".  I can glance at it and immediately know that's what the author intended.

As soon as one more thing is happening (validation in your example), then you should use a full blown constructor.  As you say, you *can* do it, but it reads a lot worse.

Really, we're only using this style because we don't have record types yet.  When we have those, I don't think we'll see this cropping up in code so much.